# script- loop through files and directories

Tags: bash

I have written the script, which unzips a zip file (passed as argument to the bash), loops through directory and files, then perform different actions based on directory or file. It is working fine.

However I would like to know some things:

1. Is it possible to do this without the unzip command? I somehow feel like that step can be avoided and we can directly use the zip file to perform the task.
2. I have used three temporary files/directories(tmp.txt - to store the directory and file lines, out.xml - for the curl command, DIREC - for finding the files and directories). I have removed those three files at the end of the script. Is there a way to optimize this? may be using variables instead of files.

Here is the bash script, with comments:

```
#!/bin/bash
#The below line unzips the zip file as passed as argument
unzip $1
length=${#1}
const=4
count=$((length-const))
DIREC=$(echo $1 | cut -b 1-$count)
OUTPUTFIL=out.xml
#The below line will find the directory, which was created by the unzip command. Creation of tmp.txt here.
find $DIREC -exec echo {} \; >tmp.txt
exec<tmp.txt
   while read line
   do
if [ -d "${line}" ] ; then
    echo "$line is a directory";
else
    if [ -f "${line}" ]; then
BASE=$(base64 $line);
        echo "${line} is a file";
{
    echo "<inpu>${BASE}</inpu>"
} > ${OUTPUTFIL}
curl -u admin:secret --data-binary @out.xml http://dp1-l2.com; echo
    else
        echo "${line} is not valid";
        exit 1
    fi
fi
   done
rm -f tmp.txt
rm -rf $DIREC
rm -f out.xml
```

Answer (score 4):

1. There's no documentation. Even a comment at the top of the script summarizing what it does would be better than nothing.
2. There's no error handling. What if the user forgets the argument?
3. This script will break if the argument `$1` contains a space. You need to write `"$1"` in several places.
4. You don't need to put `;` at the end of lines like this:

   ```
   echo "$line is a directory";
   ```
5. This code is really unclear:

   ```
   length=${#1}
   const=4
   count=$((length-const))
   DIREC=$(echo $1 | cut -b 1-$count)
   ```

   First, the variable names are poorly chosen: `length` of what? why `const`? `count` of what? Second, this assumes that `$1` ends with `.zip` and will go wrong if the file has any other name. Third, Bash has a feature [`${parameter%pattern}`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)  for removing a suffix from a string, so you can remove the extension from `$1` like this:

   ```
   DIREC=${1%.*}
   ```

   But fourth and most importantly, how do you know that the ZIP file will unpack into a directory with the same name as the ZIP file? In the example below I create a ZIP file called `b.zip` that unzips into the directory `a`:

   ```
   $ mkdir a
   $ touch a/a
   $ zip b a/a
     adding: a/a (stored 0%)
   $ rm -r a
   $ unzip b
   Archive:  b.zip
    extracting: a/a
   ```

   What you should do instead (that is, if you must unzip `$1`) is to use the `-d` option to [`unzip`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip) to extract it to a known place.

   ```
   $ unzip -d b b
   Archive:  b.zip
    extracting: b/a/a
   ```
6. Why is `OUTPUTFIL` misspelled? Why not spell it `OUTPUT_FILE`?
7. It's a bad idea to put temporary files like `$OUTPUTFIL` in the current directory. There might already be a file called `out.xml` in the current directory and then you would end up overwriting it. You should use the [`mktemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp) program to create a unique temporary file name or directory, for example like this:

   ```
   OUTPUT_FILE=$(mktemp -t unzip-XXXXXX.xml)
   ```
8. These lines have several problems:

   ```
   find $DIREC -exec echo {} \; >tmp.txt
   exec<tmp.txt
   while read line
   ```

   First, this will go wrong if `$DIREC` contains a space: you need to use quotes.
   Second, this will go wrong if `$DIREC` starts with a `-` (it will be interpreted as an option): you need to use the `-f` option to [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find).
   Third, there's no need to run a separate `echo` command for each file: [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) has a `-print` option.
   Fourth, you don't need to write the output to a temporary file in order to read it using `while read line`; you can pipe the output of [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) into the `while` loop. Like this:

   ```
   find -f "$DIREC" -- -print | while read line; do
   ```
9. Inside your `while` loop you use `[ -f ... ]` to ensure that you only process plain files (not directories). But you could use the `-type f` argument to [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to ensure that it only outputs plain files:

   ```
   find -f "$DIREC" -- -type f -print | while read line; do
   ```
10. This line will go wrong if `$line` contains a space or starts with a `-`:

    ```
    BASE=$(base64 $line);
    ```

    You should write:

    ```
    BASE=$(base64 -i "$line")
    ```
11. It's not a good idea to read the output of the [`base64`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/base64) program into a variable like this: the output might be very large and cause Bash to use large amounts of memory. It is better to let [`base64`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/base64) write its output directly to your output file, so that it does not have to be stored in a variable in Bash. Instead of:

    ```
    BASE=$(base64 $line);
    {
        echo "<inpu>${BASE}</inpu>"
    } > ${OUTPUTFIL}
    ```

    you should write:

    ```
    {
        echo "<inpu>"
        base64 -i "$line"
        echo "</inpu>"
    } > "${OUTPUT_FILE}"
    ```
12. However, there is no need for an `OUTPUT_FILE` at all here, because [`curl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) accepts the filename `-` meaning "standard input", so you can write:

    ```
    {
        echo "<inpu>"
        base64 -i "$line"
        echo "</inpu>"
    } | curl -u admin:secret --data-binary @- http://dp1-l2.com
    ```
13. `<inpu>` looks like a typo to me. Are you sure you don't mean `<input>`? If `<inpu>` is correct, you should probably add a comment to explain why.
14. It would be better to put configuration settings like `admin:secret` and `http://dp1-l2.com` in named variables at the top of the file. (It might be even better to accept them as command-line arguments.)
15. The way you have written this code means that each individual file in the archive gets uploaded as a separate XML file to the server. Is this really what you want? It seems more likely to me that you would want to upload the whole archive as one XML file. Otherwise, what's the point of using XML?
16. As you suspected, there is in fact no need to unzip the file, because you can use [`zipinfo -1`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zipinfo) to get a listing of the contents, and then use the `-p` option to [`unzip`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip) to extract a file to standard output.

Putting all this together, I would write the script line this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# upload-zip.sh -- encode contents of ZIP archive as base64
# strings in an XML document, and upload it.

# Destination and credentials for upload.
UPLOAD_URL=http://dp1-l2.com
USER=admin
PASSWORD=secret

if [ "$#" != 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 zipfile"
    exit 1
fi
ZIPFILE=$1

zipinfo -1 -- "$ZIPFILE" | while read FILE; do
    echo "<input>"
    unzip -p -- "$ZIPFILE" "$FILE" | base64
    echo "</input>"
done | curl --user "$USER:$PASSWORD" --data-binary @- --url "$UPLOAD_URL"
```